# Laplacian smoothing for inverse problem in python

Tags: python, optimization, matrix-multiplication

I am currently working in  a inverse problem, scripted in python, in which observed GPS data is used to infer the displacement below the earth (e.g and earthquake). The displacement beneath the earth can be  discretized in a grid, and the equation that describes this problems can be written as:

```
G(n*n) * S(n*1) =  U(n*1)    [1]
```

Where G is our model matrix that describes problem, S is the displacement  below the earth vector and U is the Surface Observations vector. In this case n is the number of grid points.

For penalizing "non-physical" solutions we can  regularize the inverse problem by assuming that displacement in a grid point is similar to its neighbors via a Laplacian smoothing matrix. Mathematically, what we want is minimize the Laplacian of displacement, which using matrix can be written as:

```
F(nxn) * S(n*1) =  0(n*1) [2]
```

where F is the laplacian matrix, S is the displacements column vector and "0" is a zero column vector. n is the number of grid points used in the inversion. Both equations [1] and [2]  can be optimized with methods such as `scipy.optimize.nnls` which is used in this script.

The problem is in the building of the Laplacian Matrix, I am not sure how I should start to build it; Is there any scipy or another library method that can achieve what I want? I have searched some methods in scipy for laplacian smoothing that are used for Image Processing but I don't know if they work for this particular case. The other option is building a finite difference method for the laplacian but I am unsure on how I should start creating it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/) library in Python could be an option. Considering that the displacement beneath the earth can be discretized in a grid you can build a network G(N, E) where N is the number of nodes in your grid and E all possible edges connecting your nodes N.

In each node and edge, you can apply a weight value (e.g.displacement measure).
Moreover, NetworkX has a function related to the [Laplacian Matrix calculation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.laplacianmatrix.laplacian_matrix.html).